# Microsoft.Identity.Web library distributed token cache for ASP.NET Core apps with Azure Cosmos DB. How can we re-use the cached token?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, token, azure-ad-msal, distributed-caching

**I did the implementation from this below website:**

https://dev.to/425show/implement-a-distributed-token-cache-for-asp-net-core-apps-with-azure-cosmos-db-23ai

I have used this NuGet package to store the token: **Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Cosmos**

Added the code in startup.cs file

```
    services.AddCosmosCache((CosmosCacheOptions cacheOptions) =>
{
    cacheOptions.ContainerName = Configuration["CosmosCacheContainer"];
    cacheOptions.DatabaseName = Configuration["CosmosCacheDatabase"];
    cacheOptions.ClientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(Configuration["CosmosConnectionString"]);
    cacheOptions.CreateIfNotExists = true;
});

services.AddMicrosoftWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
    .AddMicrosoftWebAppCallsWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { "User.Read", "Mail.Read" })
.AddDistributedTokenCaches();
```

Token successfully saved in the cosmos DB.

**Now I have two questions:**

1. How to get the already store token using this library Microsoft.Identity.Web extension method?
2. How the token will get renewed after expiry, Do we need to perform any extra activity?

Comment: Have you got the answer?